# Cocoa: how to remove item from Finder's context menu via service?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, contextmenu, finder

I created a service in order to show an item in the Finder's context menu.

I have the following code in my application:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [NSApp setServicesProvider:self];
    NSUpdateDynamicServices();
}
```

I'd like to remove the item from the context menu using manipulations on the service itself.

I tried to do:

```
NSUnregisterServicesProvider([[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]);
```

But it killed **all** the services for few seconds, and when it revived my service was in the services list in the Finder context menu.

How can I remove my NSService item from the finder's context menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The documentation says](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Miscellaneous/AppKit_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSUnregisterServicesProvider):

> You should not use this function to unregister the services provided by your application. For your application’s services, you should use the `setServicesProvider:` method of NSApplication, passing a `nil` argument.

So, do what you did in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`, except pass `nil` instead of `self`. (I don't know whether you'll need to do the `NSUpdateDynamicServices` step.)

Comment: by setting [NSApp setServicesProvider:nil] Finder's context menu still shows my new entries, however it disconnects the service, meaning doesn't run the target method. How can I remove the service from the Finder's context menu too?

Comment: @Nili: You probably can't. As long as your app that declares that it provides this service is installed, the service is present and, consequently, listed. (Arguably it should not show up if you have no services provider, but that's a matter for a [bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com/).)

Comment: Thanks @Peter for your answer. I will try another alternative: is there a way to disable a service visibility by code, like when you uncheck a service from the Keyboard Shortcuts -> Services tab in Prefrences? That way the service is still registered but it is not presented...

Comment: @Nili: AFAIK, there's no API for that. Only the user can toggle those on and off.

Answer (score 0):

If you, for example, have an uninstaller application, you can remove your menu item from Services menu in such way:

1. Remove the application, that provides the service (the one, in which you called `[NSApp setServicesProvider:self]`)
2. Call `NSUpdateDynamicServices()`

It rebuilds the database and checks the availability of applications, registered to provide a service.

If it doesn't help, dump the database in Terminal with `/System/Library/CoreServices/pbs -dump_pboard` and look for your service and the url, that is listed for it. There could be another copy of the application elsewhere, and the clever system found it.